# How is setTimeout() working on JS

Tags: javascript, settimeout

Just Learn JS.
In my mind, function setTimeout code area should work like normal, but it's not,exp:

```
var result = 0;
(function (i){
if(i > 0){
    result = result + i;
    i = i - 1;
    setTimeout("arguments.callee(" + i + ")",100);//arguments.callee(i);
}
else if(i == 0)
    return;
}(10));
alert(result);
```

I want it alert 55 not 10, if remove setTimeout , it'll be good.
Anybody know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
var result = 0;
(function (i, callback) {
    if (i > 0) {
        result = result + i;
        i = i - 1;
        var callee = arguments.callee;
        setTimeout(function () {
            callee(i, callback)
        }, 100);
    } else if (i == 0) {
        callback();
    }
}(10, function () {
    alert(result);
}));
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bJWHF/)

Why?
There are multiple problems in your approach

1. setTimeout is async meaning your alert will get triggered before addition operations are completed - a solution is to use a callback method which will get executed once the additions are over as shown above
2. when you pass a string to `setTimeout` it will get executed in the global scope, ie the `arguments.callee` will refer to a different object than what you will expect.

Answer (score 0):

Because `setTimeout` is *asynchronous*, which in simple terms means it's scheduled to execute later. JS does not wait for it (does not stop the code at that line), but instead runs the succeeding code.

So while you set it later, the code continues *outside* your "timeout loop" and into the alert. During this time, the loop only did one cycle, and `result` has only been added by 10.

What you can do:

- You can [set your alert at the end of your "timeout loop"](http://jsfiddle.net/CrSHF/2/)
- Alternatively, [you can send in a function, aka a "callback"](http://jsfiddle.net/CrSHF/3/) to execute when the loop is done.
- [`arguments.callee` is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/callee#Why_was_arguments.callee_deprecated.3F). You can name your IIFE and have the timeout call it

Comment: `arguments.callee` isn't deprecated, but it is prohibited in strict mode.

Answer (score 0):

Given that:

1. arguments.callee is disliked (and is not deprecated)
2. named function expressions [have their own issues](http://kangax.github.io/nfe/#jscript-bugs)
3. there seems to be a goal here of not creating a global variable to run the timeout

consider declaring the function inside the IIFE (with adjustments for what I think you want - an alert after 10 iterations showing result is 10):

```
var result = 0;

(function (i){
  function foo(j) {
    if(j > 0){
      ++result;
      setTimeout(function(){foo(--j)},100);
    } else {
      alert('Result: ' + result);
    }
  }
  foo(i);
}(10));
```

Note that there is no need for the *else* block (unless you want to return something other than `undefined`).

Oh, note that in ES5 and other browsers that support it (not IE < 9) you can pass arguments in the call to setTimeout:

```
  setTimeout(foo, 100, --j);
```

so you save an extra function object.